# how to adjust a div width to expand and shrink back on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I was doing this and thought its easy until I got stuck.
I want to expand a div with on scroll down to `100%` until the bottom of the div then at the bottom shrink back to `90%` and on scroll top doing reverse. which means the top width and the bottom width of the div only depend on scrolling up and down. 
The project is on SSR next.js
I have tried using:  [parallax](https://react-scroll-parallax.damnthat.tv/docs/examples/easing)  library which wasn't helpful 
here is a live sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ybdmbn?file=src/components/AdjustContainer.jsx

have tried to use the useEffect hook, like below

```
const [adjustWidth, setAdjustWidth] = useState()
const adjustRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [adjustRef.current]);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    console.log('scrollTop', adjustRef.current.scrollTop);
    if (adjustRef.current) {
      const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = adjustRef.current;
      if (scrollTop + clientHeight === scrollHeight) {
        // to do my stuff in here
        console.log('Reached Bottom');
      }
    }
  };
```

```
      <div className={styles.AdjustContainer}  ref={adjustRef}>

            {myContent.map((module, i) => (

                    <MyContent {...module} key={i}  />
                ))}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like instead of just checking if the user has scrolled, you need to check whether the div is in view and change the width accordingly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
    
const AdjustContainer = ({ children }) => {
  const ele = useRef();
  const [width, setWidth] = useState('90%');

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);

    observer.observe(ele.current);

    return () => {
      observer.unobserve(ele.current);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleIntersection = (entries) => {
    entries.map((entry) => {
      entry.intersectionRatio ? setWidth('100%') : setWidth('90%');
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={ele}
      className="adjustContainer"
      style={{ width, transition: 'width 2s' }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
export default AdjustContainer;
```

Comment: Is this not working as intended?

Comment: Hey man thanks for your time,  no, not yet

Comment: the 2s transition gives the page a jumping effect. I need to make the div's width increase/decrease depending on the scrolling